# Javascript promise not working how I expect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I'm trying to get to grips with promises but I can't seem to make this work correctly. 
I'm using NodeJS with Express

Expected result of my code: Console.log should print the response body

What actually happens: `console.log` prints `undefined`?

```js
http = require('http'),
req = require('request'),
reqprom =  require('request-promise'),


reqprom('myuri')
.then(function(request, response) {
    console.log(response.body);

})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Maybe response.body is undefined. What is `reqprom`?

Comment: Apologies I missed out a require 
reqprom =  require('request-promise'),

Comment: that depends upon your myuri, what it sends back in response

Comment: Doesn't look like there are ever supposed to be *two* values passed to `then`…!? https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

Comment: Shouldn't `response` be the first parameter of then, not the second?

Comment: It sends back a single number, ranging between 1-35

Comment: @JohnnyHK OF COURSE! I feel stupid now...that was obvious. thanks mate. post that as an answer if you like and I'll accept it. thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the examples for [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise), `response` should be the first (and only) parameter of `then`, so your code should look like:

```
reqprom('myuri')
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.body);    
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed this!